# How to validate non-numeric input in a numeric field in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have an entity class with some numeric attributes.
Anotations such as @NotNull, @Min and @Max are being used for validation.
Also need to check if the user input was a number and not a string.
Is there an specific anotation for that?

Comment: If you use int/long/float as the datatype of that field, will it not automatically validate that for you?

Comment: It will throw an exception on the screen if the user inputs a string. Instead, I'd like it to show a friendly message to the user as the ones allowed in the annotations. Such as when you do the following `@Min(value=100, message="Number needs to be at least 100.")
private int myNumber;`

Comment: In that case you can have controller advice that will catch the exception or override the internal message and give you the desired result.

Comment: Sure, I could do that and it would work also. But the point is that the validation annotations (@Min, @Max, @NotNull...) exist so that you don't need to do that manually like that. So was wondering if there's an anottation to check if the input is non-numeric.

Comment: Check my comments, as far as i know there isn't any existing annotation for that, you can create a custom annotation for your need, anyways i gave a sample override that can help you. This will go in your controller advice class. I edited my original answer, its in the end

Answer (score 0):

To achieve you can do something like this

POJO CLASS

```
class PojoClass {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Max(10)
    @Min(1)
    private int data;

}
```

Controller

```
@GetMapping(value = "/test")
public void test(@Valid @NotNull @RequestBody PojoClass pojo){

}
```

**Now the following scenarios work**

Case 1 : Valid Body

```
{
    "data" : 1
}
```

Case 2 : Valid Body

```
{
    "data" : "1"
}
```

This works as the String can be converted into a integer, so internally it is converted by jackson for you

**The following cases will fail**

Case 1 : Input not in range
{
"data" : 11
}

Case 2 : String cannot be desterilized into integer, i.e a string with alphabets etc
{
"data" : "1a"
}

Error in this case

> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException:
> Cannot deserialize value of type `int` from String "abc": not a valid
> Integer value

---

EDIT :

As per the comments, incase you need a custom message, you can have a controller advice and override the method in a similar way as below, Please note that this will be applicable to all the places where the user input doesn't match your POJO class.

```
@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex,
                                                              HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status,
                                                              WebRequest request) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Input is not in expected format", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Comment: Not sure I follow. I just want to validate if the numeric field got an string input. Then show the annotation message saying it's an invalid input in that case. How this code achieve this?

Comment: There is no default annotation for you to achieve this, the last method(in the edit of the answer) will go in your controller advice class and it will help you suppress that exception  message which is generated by spring and send a custom error message in that place. The validation is done by spring itself, it will try to convert that string to int and throw an error, we are catching that error and sending a custom message.

Comment: I'd need a custom message just for when the user inputs a string on an numeric field. For other validations I have other custom messages. So can't be one generic message for everything. But if there's no annotation for this I can create a simple function to do this check. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a sub-directory under the src directory with name: resources

2. Right-click the resources sub-directory and create a new file named: messages.properties
3. Add the following entry to the messages.properties file

   typeMismatch.*yourAttributeNameFromController*.*yourFieldName*=*yourCustomErrorMessage*
4. Save file
5. Add the following in your config file: WEB-INF/*yourServletName*.xml

> ```
> <bean id="messageSource"  
>  class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
>    <property name="basenames" value="resources/messages" />
> </bean>"
> ```

Validation is done :D